# Function to count string occurrences in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with a column (error_message) that registers all error messages from one of my business applications. The number of rows this application generates daily is quite large.

I want to write a generic function that counts the occurrence of certain words (for example the word "timeout") within the error_message column. The function must work with other columns as well. The return value should be INT (because it's a count).

Is there anyone who could assist me with a function like this and how to use it?

Comment: So you want both the column name and the search string to be variables? Have you already tried something that's not working?

Comment: Sorry, the column doesn't have to be a variable. But I must be able to use the same function to count other words within another column.

Comment: As @StefanoZanini asks: Have you already tried something that's not working? If so, you should include it here. If not, you should try first before posting, so you have something to include. See: [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: To do what you want, both the parameter_name and parameter value must be a variable; If it can be from different table also, then even table_name must be a variable

Answer (score 2):

This code helps you

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ErrorLog')IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ErrorLog;

CREATE table ErrorLog(Id Int Identity,[error_message] Varchar(500));
Insert into ErrorLog([error_message])
SELECT 'timeout error'      Union all
SELECT 'error at Procedure' Union all
SELECT 'timeout error'      Union all
SELECT 'Function error'     Union all
SELECT 'timeout error';

--IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ufn_ErrorCount')IS NOT NULL
--DROP FUNCTION ufn_ErrorCount

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_ErrorCount 
(
@InputErrorType Varchar(50)
)
RETURNS INT
Begin
    Declare @ErrorCOUNT INT;

    SELECT @ErrorCOUNT=COUNT([error_message])  From ErrorLog
    WHERE CHARINDEX(@InputErrorType,[error_message])>0;

RETURN @ErrorCOUNT;
END;

--Calling a Function
SELECT [dbo].[ufn_ErrorCount] ('timeout') AS ErrorCount;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a query like this

```
select  count(*)
from    yourTable
where   lower(error_message) like '%timeout%';
```

You can place that query in a function that takes both the column the search string as parameters and returns the count as an integer like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReturnSite (
    @search_column VARCHAR(50),
    @search_string VARCHAR(50)
) RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count INT;

    select  @count = count(*)
    from    yourTable
    where   lower(@search_column) like '%' + @search_string + '%';

    RETURN @count;
END;
```

Comment: isn't this the same answer as what i posted?

Comment: @Selvam It's very similar, but you know, that's the code he needs, there's not much room for creativity with such a simple task...

Comment: okay, cool ...but there was room for you to upvote my answer? anyways chuck

Comment: btw you are not setting the value for @count in that select query; also you are not returning the count; so do edit it :)

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use an inline table valued function (iTVF). Scalar UDFs perform badly and kill parallel processing but iTVF's do not.

Let's use this sample data (same as above but a few more sample records):

```
-- Sample Data
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.itvf_ErrorLogWordCount') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP FUNCTION dbo.itvf_ErrorLogWordCount;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ErrorLog') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.ErrorLog;
GO

CREATE table ErrorLog(Id Int Identity,[error_message] Varchar(500))
Insert into ErrorLog([error_message])
SELECT 'timeout error'      UNION ALL
SELECT 'error at Procedure' UNION ALL
SELECT 'timeout error'      UNION ALL
SELECT 'Function error'     UNION ALL
SELECT 'timeout error'      UNION ALL
SELECT 'Memory leak'        UNION ALL
SELECT 'CPU Fault';
GO
```

**The function:**

```
-- The function    
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.itvf_ErrorLogWordCount(@SearchString varchar(100))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
SELECT 
  SearchString = @SearchString,  
  total        = COUNT(*) 
FROM dbo.ErrorLog
WHERE error_message LIKE '%'+@SearchString+'%';
GO
```

**Autonomous use:**

```
SELECT SearchString, Total 
FROM dbo.itvf_ErrorLogWordCount('timeout');
```

Results:

```
SearchString  Total
------------- ------
timeout       3
```

**Against a series of values:**

```
WITH searchWords(SearchString) AS 
(
  SELECT 'error'   UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'timeout' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'fault'   UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'leak'
)
SELECT ss.* 
FROM searchWords
CROSS APPLY dbo.itvf_ErrorLogWordCount(SearchString) ss;
```

Results:

```
SearchString  total
------------- -----------
error         5
timeout       3
fault         1
leak          1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
--if you want to check different columns
CREATE FUNCTION function_name
( @parameter_name VARCHAR(50) 
  @parameter_value VARCHAR(50)   
)

RETURNS INT

AS

BEGIN

   DECLARE @count INT;

   --executable_section
   Select @count=count(*) from table_name where @parameter_name like '%'+@parameter_value+'%';

   RETURN @count;

END;

--if you want to use the same column but different value  
CREATE FUNCTION function_name
( 
  @parameter VARCHAR(50)  
)

RETURNS INT

AS

BEGIN

   DECLARE @count INT;

   --executable_section
   Select @count=count(*) from table_name where error_message like '%'+@parameter_value+'%';

   RETURN @count;

END;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountOccurrencesOfString
(
    @searchTerm nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count INT;
    SELECT @count=COUNT([error_message])  From table
        WHERE CHARINDEX(@searchTerm, [error_message]) > 0;
    return @count;
END;
```

hope it will helps you.